# ListBox ItemTemplate Background Transparent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I am trying to set the Background to Transparent, however as you can see in the screen shot below when the mouse hovers over the `ListBoxItem` it shows a blue Rectangle over the item:

[image: ListViewItem Screen Shot]

I am using MVVM and my implementation is as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HyperLinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0066CC"/>
        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="None" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0066CC"/>
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
        <ListBox x:Name="TeamListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" BorderThickness="0" 
                 SelectionMode="Single" Background="Transparent">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0, 0, 0, 5">
                            <Hyperlink Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource HyperLinkStyle}}" 
                                       Command="{Binding ElementName=TeamListView, Path=DataContext.ConnectToTeam}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Notes:

1. The hyperlinkstyle is used to give a hyperlink feel to the hyperlink control with in listbox.
2. The listbox 'TeamListView' uses an ItemTemplate DataTemplate. The style for the ItemTemplate is ListBoxItem, by setting background to transparent onMouseHover the intention is to remove the blue with no color on hover.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this in `ListBox.Resources` and remove `IsMouseOver` trigger:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
</ListBox.Resources>
```

In system has default highlight brush depending on your system theme. To change this value, it is necessary to turn to `SystemColors`.

Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightbrushkey.aspx):

> The SystemColors class provides access to system brushes and colors, such as ControlBrush, ControlBrushKey, and DesktopBrush. A system brush is a SolidColorBrush object that paints an area with the specified system color. A system brush always produces a solid fill; it can't be used to create a gradient.
>
> You can use system brushes as either a static or a dynamic resource. Use a dynamic resource if you want the brush to update automatically if the user changes the system brush as the application is running; otherwise, use a static resource.

In `.NET 4.5` system does not use `SystemColors`, therefore, you should:

- create the your `Style/ControlTemplate`
- look for alternatives, for example here: [List/Combo Box Background And Selected Colours Under .net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007918/list-combo-box-background-and-selected-colours-under-net-4-5)
- See this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750655/selected-listboxitem-does-not-have-a-background-of-controlbrushkey-when-app-is-unfocused), which shows how to remove the difference between the frameworks

Comment: i don't understand why you have to change the system color itself , 
why can't it be replaced by a different value source?

Comment: @eran otzap: I did not little understand, can you describe in detail your question?

Comment: why are giving a new value to SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey 
and not the Background of the listboxitem , why is that ? 
why can't the Background property of the ListBoxItem be changed directly ?

Comment: Thank you sir! That was it, .NET 4.5, your suggestion solved it. Thank you. I followed the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007918/list-combo-box-background-and-selected-colours-under-net-4-5

Comment: @eran otzap: Please read quote in my answer. `SystemColors` - This is the class that contains static variables in the colors. This is done because, system has default highlight brush *depending* on your system theme. It turns out, that the values of colors the system are taken from this class `SystemColors` and does not take the color that you're setting in the trigger. This construction it was designed by WPF developers.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the Highlighting of your `ListBoxItem` you can just set the system colors to do it like below:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
     <Style.Resources>  
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" color="Transparent" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </Style.Resources>
```

Comment: Why is that , once the property has been set by a dynamic resource can't it be overridden ?

Comment: Doesn't work. After adding this style definition in the UserControl.Resources I don't see any impact to the Background colour, do I need to do anything additional to associate this style to the ListBoxItem?

Comment: @Tarun Arora: You using .NET 4.5?

Comment: @Tarun Arora: Please read my answer, where it is said about `.NET 4.5`.