# Override the background color when ListBox is disabled/inactived

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles, itemcontainerstyle

I want to have everything of the `ListBox` background **transparent**. Not focused/focused/whatever...

I override the style of the `ListBox` and its `ItemContainerStyle` but I still have a background color on the `ListBox` when it is disabled by another element...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="MyListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TransparentBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MyListBoxItemStyle}"/>
</Style>



<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="MyListBoxItemStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource TransparentColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource TransparentColor}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I also tried by setting the `FocusVisualStyle` to null (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13688387/2755741)) ; to set some "inactive" colors brush`System.Colors` to transparent and to set the ScrollBar colors to transparent (see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SystemColors_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) but nothing is working...

- What am I missing ?
- Do you know which color can be the problem (see this [post](http://stuff.seans.com/2011/02/15/creating-a-listbox-that-shows-all-predefined-system-colors/)) ?
- What will be is state ? Disable ? Inactive ?

Comment: You also need to set the SystemColors.ControlBrushKey to transparent for the ListBox, not just for the ListBoxItem

Comment: The ListBox control template informs us that it is DisabledControlLightColor which in turn is defined as #FFE8EDF9.  You need to override these

Comment: @GayotFow, where did you get that from? The official standard WPF themes/styles don't have/use "DisabledControlLightColor"...

Comment: @elgonzo, it's in the control template.  You need to override it.  I would just import it wholesale and change bits by trial and error until you got what you were after.

Comment: @GayotFow, no, i asked WHERE you got that from. The only place i know of are examples in the MSDN documentation but which are about defining your own **custom template with custom resources**, not about overriding resources of the **standard themes/styles** (that includes the standard control templates).

Comment: My mistake.  That comment was directed toward the OP.

Comment: @GayotFow, the comment does not change its meaning whether i read it or the OP reads it. o_O

Comment: To answer your question then:  I got it from the control template.  Hopefully that meets with your approval as the logical place to look :)

Comment: @GayotFow, again where is that secret omnious control template you are speaking about? It certainly is not any control template that is coming as part of WPF with any .NET distributable.

Comment: @GayotFow, why should i **not** say that? I still wait for the proof of your claim. On the other hand, i will not prove my claim myself. I will let Microsoft provide the proof of my claim: try finding your "DisabledControlLightColor" in the [reference sources of the .NET framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) -- you can search as long as you want, you won't find it...

Comment: Ok.  That's fine.    The last comment is yours if you want it.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to do by changing a colour globally because you get confounding effects from other controls.

Changing the background colour of a list box to match a given state, like inactive or disabled can be approached by getting a plain-vanilla list box template like this one...

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"  Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="false">
                            <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DisabledControlLightColor}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderLightColor}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                        </Border.Background>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

...and adding it to your window resources.  Note that the template refers to a set of colours which get defined further up the object graph as...

```
    <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>
```

... these can be replaced with the WPF value for Transparent, which is  #00FFFFFF.  This will change *ALL* colours to transparent where ever the references exist in the template. The StoryBoard colours refer to system colours and will need to be changed individually.  Or delete the story boards altogether.

Once you get a working model for your desired styling you can add a key to the resource and style list boxes selectively.

As posted, this all compiled and ran clean under 4.5...

Interesting links are...

[ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754242%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Color values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx)

And a very useful utility for inspecting templates in the WPF dll's:  http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/ShowMeTheTemplate.zip

Comment: You answered to one of my concern that was the changing of a global color. I do not like to override global colors so your answer avoided me that ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @MyRestlessDream, are you going to use the template strategy?

Comment: Yes I am. It's doing exactly what I want without touching the SystemColors so it's perfect!